# saving php array to mariadb dynamic colum

Tags: php, arrays, mariadb

I have an array like this

```
   $test = array(
        'Subscription' => '1',
        'Streaming' => '1',
        'Download' =>  '0'
    )
```

so during updating to mariaDB

```
  $query = 'UPDATE table_1 set category_dynamic = COLUMN_CREATE(' . $test . ') where id = 1';
  $this->Model->query($query);
```

I want to save the array this way `('Subscription',1,'Streaming',1,'Download',0)`

any suggestion ?

Comment: Try `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
<?php

$test = array(
        'Subscription' => '1',
        'Streaming' => '1',
        'Download' =>  '0'
);

$data = '';
foreach($test as $key=>$value)
{
    $data .= '"'.$key.'"'.', '.$value.', ';
}

$data = rtrim($data,', ');

$query = 'UPDATE table_1 set category_dynamic = COLUMN_CREATE(' . $data . ') where id = 1';
```

Hope it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) for that.

```
$test = array(
        'Subscription' => '1',
        'Streaming' => '1',
        'Download' =>  '0'
    );
$list = implode(',', array_map(function ($v, $k) { return "'".$k."'" . ',' . $v; }, $test, array_keys($test)));


$query = 'UPDATE table_1 set category_dynamic = COLUMN_CREATE(' . $list . ') where id = 1';
$this->Model->query($query);
```